# "Charms of life" - is it correct English?

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

I have a question, which for some of you may be really obvious, but I decided to ask, is the phrase 'Charms of life' 100% English correct? The context is - describing the good things that happens to us and something we like in life.

Comment: Is this a phrase you created yourself? Why do you think it might be incorrect? See [**Details, please!**](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Charms of life* is fine, and although it is more usual to see it in the singular form as an uncountable noun (*that's the charm of life*), the word *charm* can be countable. It sits alongside the more usual *pleasures of life*, *joys of life* and *beauty of life* very well.